# Show the set of bounded function is closed and open.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a set and $(M, d)$ be a metric space. Define $d_{\infty} = \sup\{d(f(x), g(x) \rvert x \in X\}$. Recall that $f : X \rightarrow M$ is bounded if $f(X) \subset B_r(a) = \{m \in M \rvert d(m, a) < r\}$ for some $r \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $a \in M$. Show the set $\mathcal B(X, M) = \{f : X \rightarrow M \rvert f$ bounded$\} \subset M^X$, where $M^X$ is the set of functions $X \rightarrow M$, is closed and open.

Could anyone provide hints as I have no idea on how to start this question.

Comment: Hints:

Closed: if a sequence in ${\cal B}(X, M)$ convergence to some $f : X \right M$, then $f$ necessarily turns out to be bounded (i.e., lies in ${\cal B}(X, M)$).

Open: every $f$ in ${\cal B}(X, M)$ has an open neighborhood in ${\cal B}(X, M)$.

First, experiment with examples you can graph; e.g., with $X = [0, 1]$, or even with $X$ finite.

Comment: If you want to talk about some subset of $M^X$ being closed or open, you probably should say what *topology* on $M^X$ you consider. Perhaps it might seem that you want to consider $d_\infty$ as a metric on $M^X$, but AFAICT $d_\infty(0,f)$ is only defined if $f$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $f \in \mathcal{B}(X,M)$, show there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $D_{\infty}(f,\epsilon) := \{h \in M^X : d_{\infty}(f,h) < \epsilon \} \subset \mathcal{B}(X,M)$, therefore yielding that $\mathcal{B}(X,M)$ is open. To show $\mathcal{B}(X,M)$ is closed, show that $\mathcal{B}(X,M)^c$ is open using a similar argument as above.

Comment: What is $\mathcal B(X, M)^c$>

Comment: @user372834 $\mathcal{B}(X, M)^c = M^X - \mathcal{B}(X, M)$